# passing pointers to function that takes a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

In C++, when you have a function that takes a reference to an object, how can you pass an object pointer to it?

As so:

```
Myobject * obj = new Myobject();

somefunc(obj);  //-> Does not work?? Illegal cast??

somefunc(Myobject& b)
{
 // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just dereference the pointer, resulting in the lvalue:

```
somefun(*obj);
```

Answer (score 5):

you just have to do :

```
somfunc(*obj);
```